# Dividing a list of arrays to a smaller list of arrays

Tags: python

In my current research project, I have a list of arrays similar to the one shown bellow:

```
import numpy as np
[np.array([ 0.00727845,  0.00363923, -0.00976286, -0.00488143]),
 np.array([ 0.00493276,  0.00246638, -0.00893927, -0.00446964]),
 np.array([ 0.00283457,  0.00141729, -0.00780608, -0.00390304]),
 np.array([ 0.00104456,  0.00052228, -0.00649412, -0.00324706]),
 np.array([-0.00040696, -0.00020348, -0.00511511, -0.00255755]),
 np.array([-0.00151502, -0.00075751, -0.00375973, -0.00187987])]
```

Here, the length of each individual array is the same. let it e `N`
Then I need to separate each array in to half and collect them separately.

That is:

```
list_1 = 
[np.array([ 0.00727845,  0.00363923, ]),
 np.array([ 0.00493276,  0.00246638, ]),
 np.array([ 0.00283457,  0.00141729, ]),
 np.array([ 0.00104456,  0.00052228, ]),
 np.array([-0.00040696, -0.00020348, ]),
 array([-0.00151502, -0.00075751, ])]

list_2 =
np.array([ -0.00976286, -0.00488143]),
 np.array([ -0.00893927, -0.00446964]),
 np.array([-0.00780608, -0.00390304]),
 np.array([  -0.00649412, -0.00324706]),
 np.array([ -0.00511511, -0.00255755]),
 array([ -0.00375973, -0.00187987])]
```

I can think of a very lengthy method using for loops to do this but I suppose there is a better way of handling. Appreciate your help

Comment: Your array could won't even compile, because the first argument to `array(...)` must be the type.  Please fix your code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I apologize.  I'm dealing with numpy arrays and I edited my code

Comment: Rather than including the console output of what the Numpy array looks like when printing, instead show us the actual Python code you used to create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use a list comprehension approach here:

```py
import numpy as np

inp = [
    np.array([ 0.00727845,  0.00363923, -0.00976286, -0.00488143]),
    np.array([ 0.00493276,  0.00246638, -0.00893927, -0.00446964]),
    np.array([ 0.00283457,  0.00141729, -0.00780608, -0.00390304]),
    np.array([ 0.00104456,  0.00052228, -0.00649412, -0.00324706]),
    np.array([-0.00040696, -0.00020348, -0.00511511, -0.00255755]),
    np.array([-0.00151502, -0.00075751, -0.00375973, -0.00187987])
]
list_1 = [np.array(x[0:2]) for x in inp]
list_2 = [np.array(x[2:4]) for x in inp]
print(list_1)
```

This prints:

```
 [array([0.00727845, 0.00363923]),
  array([0.00493276, 0.00246638]),
  array([0.00283457, 0.00141729]),
  array([0.00104456, 0.00052228]),
  array([-0.00040696, -0.00020348]),
  array([-0.00151502, -0.00075751])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using loops you can make a numpy array from the list and use indices which will be faster:

```
import numpy as np
N=20
inner=np.arange(N)
some_list= [inner for i in range(N)]
arr = np.array(some_list)

arr1 = arr[:,:int(N/2)]
arr2= arr[:,int(N/2):]
```

If N is odd then arr2 will get N/2+1 columns so be aware of that (if you want that arr1 will get the extra column you should use N/2+1 instead of N/2)

If you must store it in lists you can convert np.array into list with arr.to_list()

Comment: You can use `N // 2` to do integer division; no need to convert to floating-point and back.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the functionality of numpy:

```
import numpy as np
l = [np.array([ 0.00727845,  0.00363923, -0.00976286, -0.00488143]),
 np.array([ 0.00493276,  0.00246638, -0.00893927, -0.00446964]),
 np.array([ 0.00283457,  0.00141729, -0.00780608, -0.00390304]),
 np.array([ 0.00104456,  0.00052228, -0.00649412, -0.00324706]),
 np.array([-0.00040696, -0.00020348, -0.00511511, -0.00255755]),
 np.array([-0.00151502, -0.00075751, -0.00375973, -0.00187987])]

l = np.array(l)

print(l)
>>> array([[ 0.00727845,  0.00363923, -0.00976286, -0.00488143],
       [ 0.00493276,  0.00246638, -0.00893927, -0.00446964],
       [ 0.00283457,  0.00141729, -0.00780608, -0.00390304],
       [ 0.00104456,  0.00052228, -0.00649412, -0.00324706],
       [-0.00040696, -0.00020348, -0.00511511, -0.00255755],
       [-0.00151502, -0.00075751, -0.00375973, -0.00187987]])

list_1 = l[:, :2]
print(list_1)
>>> array([[ 0.00727845,  0.00363923],
       [ 0.00493276,  0.00246638],
       [ 0.00283457,  0.00141729],
       [ 0.00104456,  0.00052228],
       [-0.00040696, -0.00020348],
       [-0.00151502, -0.00075751]])

list_2 = l[:, 2:]
print(list_2)
>>> array([[-0.00976286, -0.00488143],
       [-0.00893927, -0.00446964],
       [-0.00780608, -0.00390304],
       [-0.00649412, -0.00324706],
       [-0.00511511, -0.00255755],
       [-0.00375973, -0.00187987]])
```